Automorphism group of a real simple Lie algebra
Question: Let $\mathfrak g$ be a real finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra of non-compact type.
What is the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$ of $\mathfrak g$?
Non-compact above means that the Killing form of $\mathfrak g$ is not negative-definite.  The automorphism group of $\mathfrak g$ is the set of all Lie algebra automorphisms of $\mathfrak g$. The automorphism group of $\mathfrak g$ is  a Lie group.
I am looking for some references describing a formula or an algorithm to compute $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$. I am particularly interested in the cases when $\mathfrak g$ is $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb R)$, $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$, $\mathfrak{so}(n,1)$, or $\mathfrak{su}(n,1)$.
What I know so far: Let $\text{Inn}(\mathfrak g)$ denote the identity component of $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$, which we call the adjoint group of $\mathfrak g$. The adjoint group can be constructed in the following manner: take any connected Lie group $G$ whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak g$. Then the adjoint representation $\text{Ad}: G \rightarrow \text{Inn}(\mathfrak g)$ has discrete kernel $Z(G)$, so $G/Z(G) \cong \text{Inn}(\mathfrak g)$. Thus the problem of computing $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$ reduces to computing the discrete outer automorphism group $\text{Out}(\mathfrak g) :=\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g) / \text{Inn}(\mathfrak g)$, and finding representatives for the cosets in $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$.
Context: I want to compute the isometry groups of irreducible symmetric spaces of non-compact type. We have a bijection
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} \text{Irreducible symmetric spaces of non-compact type}  \\ \text{ up to isometry and scaling}\end{matrix} \right\}\longleftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} \text{Finite-dimensional real simple Lie algebras}  \\ \text{of non-compact type up to isomorphism}\end{matrix} \right\}.$$
The bijection is given as follows: given an irreducible symmetric space of non-compact type $(M,g)$, the Lie algebra of the isometry group of $(M,g)$ is a real simple Lie algebra of non-compact type. Conversely, given a real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of non-compact type, there is an algorithm to construct an irreducible symmetric space of non-compact type $(M,g)$, with $\mathfrak g$ being the Lie algebra of the isometry group of $(M,g)$. The key is that the isometry group of $(M,g)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$: see Helgason Chapter VI Exercise 7(iii).

In the case of complex Lie algebras it is the semidirect product of the adjoint group and the group of automorphisms of the Dynkin diagram.

This can be found in the literature. For example, ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R))\cong SO(1,2)$, see here, Proposition $2.5$.
